# 90s game about a man with a revolver fighting demons

Tags: identify-this-game

The game I'm trying to identify is a side-scrolling platformer where the protagonist is a man wielding a six-shooter revolver. I think I played a demo or shareware version as it only contained one level (or even portion of it). The level  was a castle interior, and you had to shoot some sort of demons - [chorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chort) perhaps, at least they looked similar. I'm pretty sure they were gray, had pig noses, and wielded polearms.

Like I said, it was probably a demo or shareware, and after you did some progress a full-screen picture with some text appeared and you couldn't play anymore. I think the text was in German. There was a demon - or perhaps minotaur? - and a damsel in distress.

Some other facts I remember:

- I played it under Windows (but it is likely to be a DOS game)
- I think there was no title screen / menu. You launched the .exe and immediately started to play.
- Also I wasn't able to find an obvious way to exit the game. After the full-screen message I just killed the process.
- Ammo was limited. I think the GUI contained a revolver cylinder showing how much bullets you have left.
- I think I played it around '95-98 (but the game is probably way older - beginning of 90s perhaps?)

It was long time ago, so some of these details may be distored or plain false memories.

Does any of it rings a bell?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since this question is about a game, and a moderately recent one (from a retrocomputing point of view), it may be better suited for [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), the gaming StackExchange. That StackExchange also has on the order of ten times the number of users there are here.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson thank you for your suggestion. It seems however that game identification questions (at least ones lacking a screenshot / video / audio clip) are considered off-topic at Arqade. As for the game being moderately recent - while I did play it around '95-98 I think the game is actually way older (beginning of 90s perhaps?). I'll add that to the question.

Comment: There's an active Meta topic here, that's questioning whether "I remember a game that..." should be suggested to be asked here when people are rejected from Arqade.  So far, the discussion is going towards "No, definitely not." https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/777/does-retrocomputing-want-to-be-featured-as-a-place-to-go-for-identifying-retro-g?cb=1

Comment: @Ghedipunk Well, to be more precise, the discussion's current result seems to be hovering around, "we don't want questions Arqade has closed moved here," but that "I remember..." questions are not really a problem here yet. So for the moment I, at least, am fine with leaving this question open and seeing where things go.

Comment: Was it Wolfenstein?

Comment: Two other places you could check are the /r/TipOfMyJoystick subreddit and the #identify-a-game channel on the MobyGames Discord... both of which are dedicated to this kind of question.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that comes to mind for a side scroller about a man with a revolver is ***Rick Dangerous***, which was on many platforms including PC and Amiga.

Following image is from the Amiga game database Hall of Light. Notice the remaining bullets shown across the top of the screen.

[image]